# Fill existing table with JSON data using ajax

Tags: html, mysql, json, ajax, html-table

I have been searching for a while for a way to populate a existing html table with delimited JSON.

What I have so far:
api.php that fetches the data from mysql database:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = 'SELECT id, username, level, email, active, last_login FROM cpusers LIMIT ' . $id . ', 10';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
for(
    $array = array();
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $array[] = $row
);
echo json_encode($array);
```

And my HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js">

    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

        var mydata = '';
        var previd = parseInt($("#prev").attr('data-firstid'));
        var nextid = parseInt($("#next").attr('data-lastid'));
        var actualid = 0;

        function getdata(value) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                url: "api.php",
                data: 'table=id='+value, 
                success: function(data){
                    mydata = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
                }
            });
        }

            if ( previd == -1 && nextid == -1 ) {
                getdata(actualid)
                pageMe(mydata);
                if (mydata.length < 10) {
                    $("#next").hide();
                } else {
                    nextid = actualid + 1;
                    $("#next").attr("data-lastid", nextid);
                    $("#next").show();
                }
            }

            if ( previd == -1  ) {
                $("#prev").hide();
            } else {
                $("#prev").show();
            }

            //register your click event
            $("#prev").click(function() {
                actualid = parseInt($(this).attr('data-firstid'));
                previd = actualid - 1;
                nextid = actualid + 1;
                getdata(actualid);
                pageMe(mydata);
                $("#prev").attr("data-firstid", previd);
                $("#next").attr("data-lastid", nextid);
                if ( previd == -1  ) {
                    $("#prev").hide();
                } else {
                    $("#prev").show();
                }
            });

            $("#next").click(function() {
                actualid = parseInt($(this).attr('data-lastid'));
                previd = actualid - 1;
                getdata(actualid);
                pageMe(mydata);
                $("#prev").attr("data-firstid", previd);
                $("#prev").show();
                if (mydata.length < 10) {
                    $("#next").hide();
                } else {
                    nextid = actualid + 1;
                    $("#next").attr("data-lastid", nextid);
                    $("#next").show();
                }
            });
        });

        function pageMe(data) {
            clearMyTable();
            if (typeof data == 'undefined') return;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var rowdata = data[i];
                if (typeof rowdata == 'undefined') break;
                $("#" + i + "0").text(rowdata.username);
                $("#" + i + "1").text(rowdata.email);
                $("#" + i + "2").text(rowdata.level);
                $("#" + i + "3").text(rowdata.last_login);
                $("#" + i + "4").text(rowdata.active);
            }
        }

        function clearMyTable()
        {
           for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                $("#" + i + "0").text("");
                $("#" + i + "1").text("");
                $("#" + i + "2").text("");
                $("#" + i + "3").text("");
                $("#" + i + "4").text("");

            } 
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
        <tr id="header">
            <td align="center">Account</td>
            <td align="center">Email Address</td>
            <td align="center">Level</td>
            <td align="center">Last Login</td>
            <td align="center">Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line0">
            <td align="center" id="00">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="01">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="02">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="03">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="04">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line1">
            <td align="center" id="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="11">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="12">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="13">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="14">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line2">
            <td align="center" id="20">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="21">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="22">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="23">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="24">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line3">
            <td align="center" id="30">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="31">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="32">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="33">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="34">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line4">
            <td align="center" id="40">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="41">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="42">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="43">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="44">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line5">
            <td align="center" id="50">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="51">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="52">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="53">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="54">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line6">
            <td align="center" id="60">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="61">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="62">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="63">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="64">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line7">
            <td align="center" id="70">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="71">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="72">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="73">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="74">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line8">
            <td align="center" id="80">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="81">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="82">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="83">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="84">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line9">
            <td align="center" id="90">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="91">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="92">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="93">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="94">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Pagination">
            <td align="center" colspan="2"><a id="prev" data-firstid="-1" href="#">Previous</a>

            </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="3"><a id="next" data-lastid="-1" href="#">Next</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

And I can't get this to work.
When the page loads, the table should be populated with mysql data starting from the id "0". And then use the links "Previous" and "Next" to paginate. When reaching the end of the mysql data, the table should be filled with the data and leave blank the rest of the cells.
I need to have all the time the 12 rows table.

Any help/suggestions appreciated.
Note: all the examples I found I saw the ajax building the html table, and none for a table already created. I don't want to create the table dynamically because it will break all my visuals.

Comment: What does not work ? Do you have errors ?

Comment: I don't get any errors and the info is not shown.

Comment: `console.log(obj)` ... You will understand you have to make a loop in the success

Comment: I understand that ajax needs to iterate all json... but my javascript/ajax skills are very low. And also, i understand that i need a variable external of the function to save the actual start id for the previous next buttons. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: @BrunoCarvalho Check my new edit and please do not edit my answer - it gets confusing. If you want to add more examples edit your question and add the example there. I hope this helps and if it is please mark as accepted answer ;)

Comment: Ok, i commented the json data from the file and uncommented the call to the API. I also commented the loop. done this before moving forward for the "next" button... Run the page and... "Uncaught ReferenceError: mydata is not defined" I guess i need somehow to put the json call somewhere just after the function()... but if i do so, it doesn't catch up the id from the <a>. If i let it where it is now, the error that shows up on my console is the first pageMe(mydata) if i am not wrong... so... where do i put my json call? :(

Comment: ok... i understanded... suposely, the buttons prev and next should change the start id and call the ajax...

Comment: Ok i maded alot of rewrites and could finally figure it out.
Thanks for your help, your code putted me on the right path.
I updated my code with my final changes.

Comment: Sorry i did not see you comments earlier. My point was that you could of replaced pageMe(pagedata); in my code whith the commented code bellow it and it should of worked. But the great news is that you make it work by your self! Good job and take care.

Comment: i saw and tested it... but i got alot of ReferenceErrors... so i needed to put the call somewhere else and figure a way to link it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the free [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) for your purpose? It was working perfectly for me in a similar situation and it has great support here in stack overflow.
Check their demo with php server side like yours:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

BTW they have commercially supported server side component too but the javascript version is completely free.

declaimer: no connection with the company just happy user of the free component.

EDIT:
I see several issues with your js code:

1. `$('.previouspage').click(function()` is not properly ended - } must be }); line 27 in your original html.
2. `$('.previouspage').click(function()` registers onClick event for elements that will be searched for by class - you don't have that class. You can test this by just adding class="previouspage" to your  element, and it will be activated on clicking .. BTW when do you plan to load your first page?
3. your Line0 tr should have elements with id 10,11,12... not 11,12,13...

Here is my working sample with array of data (I can't use your server side at the moment).

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js">
        
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        var mydata = [{
            id: "0",
            username: "test0",
            level: "1",
            email: "e@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "1",
            username: "test1",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "2",
            username: "test2",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "3",
            username: "test3",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "4",
            username: "test4",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "5",
            username: "test5",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "6",
            username: "test6",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "7",
            username: "test7",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "8",
            username: "test8",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "9",
            username: "test9",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "10",
            username: "test10",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "11",
            username: "test11",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }, {
            id: "12",
            username: "test12",
            level: "2",
            email: "eccc@e.com",
            active: "true",
            last_login: "2007-10-01"
        }];

        $(function() {

   var firstid = $("#prev").attr('data-firstid');
   var lastid = $("#next").attr('data-lastid');
  
            if ( firstid == -1 && lastid == -1 )
            {
                pageMe(mydata);

            }
   
   if ( firstid < 1  )
            {
                
    $("#prev").hide();

            }
   else {
     $("#prev").show();
   }


            //register your click event
            $("#prev").click(function() {
   
                var id = parseInt($(this).attr('data-firstid'));
         
    var start = Math.max(0, id-11);
    var end = Math.max(10, id-1);
    var pagedata = mydata.slice(start, end);
                        
                pageMe(pagedata);   

//for ajax you should have something like:
//  $.ajax({
//            type: "GET",
//            url: "api.php",
//            data: 'id='+start, 
//            success: pageMe  //NOTE no passing arguments!
//  });            

            });

            $("#next").click(function() {
   
                var id = parseInt($(this).attr('data-lastid'));
    
    if (id < -1) id = -1;
    
                var pagedata = mydata.slice(id+1, id+11);
                pageMe(pagedata);
    
    $("#prev").show();

            });


        });

        function pageMe(data) {

            clearMyTable();

   if (typeof data == 'undefined') return;
   
   if (data.length < 10) {
     $("#next").hide();
   }
   else {
     $("#next").show();
   }
   
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   
     
                //that is single row for the table - the server will limit rows to ten
                var rowdata = data[i];

                if (typeof rowdata == 'undefined') break;
    
    

                if (i==0)
                {
                    //setting the prev id
                    $("#prev").attr("data-firstid", parseInt(rowdata.id));
                }

                $("#" + i + "0").text(rowdata.username);
                $("#" + i + "1").text(rowdata.email);
                $("#" + i + "2").text(rowdata.level);
                $("#" + i + "3").text(rowdata.last_login);
                $("#" + i + "4").text(rowdata.active);

                if (i == (data.length - 1) || i == 9 )
                {
                    //setting the prev id
                    $("#next").attr("data-lastid", parseInt(rowdata.id));
     break;
                }

            }

        }

        function clearMyTable()
        {
           for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                $("#prev").attr("data-firstid", -1);
    $("#next").attr("data-lastid", -1);
                $("#" + i + "0").text("");
                $("#" + i + "1").text("");
                $("#" + i + "2").text("");
                $("#" + i + "3").text("");
                $("#" + i + "4").text("");
                
            } 
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
        <tr id="header">
            <td align="center">Account</td>
            <td align="center">Email Address</td>
            <td align="center">Level</td>
            <td align="center">Last Login</td>
            <td align="center">Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line0">
            <td align="center" id="00">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="01">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="02">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="03">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="04">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line1">
            <td align="center" id="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="11">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="12">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="13">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="14">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line2">
            <td align="center" id="20">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="21">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="22">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="23">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="24">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line3">
            <td align="center" id="30">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="31">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="32">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="33">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="34">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line4">
            <td align="center" id="40">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="41">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="42">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="43">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="44">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line5">
            <td align="center" id="50">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="51">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="52">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="53">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="54">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line6">
            <td align="center" id="60">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="61">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="62">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="63">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="64">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line7">
            <td align="center" id="70">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="71">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="72">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="73">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="74">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line8">
            <td align="center" id="80">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="81">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="82">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="83">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="84">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Line9">
            <td align="center" id="90">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="91">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="92">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="93">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" id="94">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Pagination">
            <td align="center" colspan="2"><a id="prev" data-firstid="-1" href="#">Previous</a>

            </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="3"><a id="next" data-lastid="-1" href="#">Next</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT 3:
OK now we are looking my code above. You need to remove the array manipulation with calls to your ajax.
You need to figure out how to call the ajax for the next :)
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have looked at jqGrid... but it doesn't solve my problem. I don't want the table be builded! I want the table be filled. It's different and jqGrid doesn't do it. :(

Comment: My table has 10 rows and 5 columns, despite of being empty, they are there already. I want to put the json values there and use the buttons to page the table. All exemples i saw till now are for building the table itself (by building the whole table or adding new lines) and that doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: OK - I sow just now your last paragraph about not building the table. Sorry about that. Let me try to dig something more ...

Comment: BTW you can limit the rows on the jqGrid, that way keeping them 10, but this will still build them.

Comment: I noticed it when i tested it... but the problem with jqGrid is that if you are reaching the end of the data or if you have only 5 results, it doesn't build the rest of the table to get 10 total rows. It creates like a viewport and fills the table inside it, and when reaching the end of the data, it simply shows "blank space".

From my point of view, it looks more professional showing up empty cells to fill up the empty space. (But it's only my point of view)

Comment: ok... i changed a bit the code to make the div ids different from the data id (That way the table can still work if the db has big ids) and tryed to make the pagination work.
Also, i can't figure out how to replace your mydata with my json source... (i guess im too dumb! :D )
Anyway, i update your code with the modifications i made to your code.

Comment: id = $(this).attr('id');

Comment: Doesn't work. I tryed it too...
I can't understand why it only shows the 9th row of json. :(

Comment: check my EDIT 2. I could give you example tomorrow.

Comment: server side SQL is correct. The php is reading the $_GET['id'] variable which is 1 or any other number after clicking on the prev or next links. And the <a> links also have the id which should be updated after running the ajax... what doesn't happen. And answering your previous question, yep, i want the table filled on page load and then use the links to paginate it.